# Usando Linq to sql, como eu obtenho a consulta sql gerada?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle, linq-to-sql

Olá.

Se eu tiver um exemplo:

```
        var agendamento = _repository.First(a => a.iid == id
                                 && a.locIid == _usuario.LocalidadeContextoId
                                 && a.activeVersion == 0, "", true);
```

Consigo saber a consulta `SQL` gerada?

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic banco oracle

Comment: @itasouza você está usando `Entity Framework`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando o *IQueryable*, é possível obter o *SQL* gerado.

```
IQueryable<SuaClasse> query = _repository.First(a => a.iid == id
                             && a.locIid == _usuario.LocalidadeContextoId
                             && a.activeVersion == 0, "", true);

 var querySql = query.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte no seu `context`:

```
public DatabaseContext() : base("MeuContext")
    {
        //Trecho abaixo utilizado para ver as querys geradas pelo Entity
        #if DEBUG
        Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        #endif
    }
```

Esse trecho `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)` vai fazer com que toda `query` gerada apareça no **Output** quando você estiver debugando.

A resposta que utiliza o `IQueryable` também é válida, mas geralmente é melhor usar da forma que apresentei aqui, pois você quer conferir como ficou sua consulta durante o desenvolvimento e manutenção da aplicação para garantir que está trazendo as informações corretamente.

Claro que isso não tira a validade da opção usando `IQueryble` e dependendo do que deseja ele pode ser mais útil.